# cbind in for loop with unequal number of rows

Tags: r

This is my data frame

```
>head(dat)
  Var1 Freq
1   89    2
2   95    2
3   97    1
4   99    2
5  103    2
6  104    2
```

I want to iterate over `for` loop and append `dat$freq` using `cbind`. Is it possible to append the `Freq` to the same `Var1`, when `NA` occurs in `Freq`?

Comment: Your questions doesn't make sense. What do you want to achieve exactly (show the desired result!) and why do you need a `for` loop?

Comment: @Roland: I apologize for the confusion. I get these `dat` in `for` loop, each time i need to append to the existing data frame like `dat1<-cbind(dat1, dat$Freq)`. My question, is it possible to append in a same row, when unequal number of rows exists. For example, 10 rows appearing in first cycle, then 9, then 8, how to deal with this? Missing may happen in any row, how to identify it?

Comment: Don't grow an object in a loop. That's the most inefficient operation you can do in R. However, if a value is missing, you should fill in an `NA` value.

Comment: i.e. Roland is refering to preallocating memory to an object, preferably of the same size as the one you wish to have at the end.
e.g. `matrix()`.

Comment: @Roland, @Toby: Thanks for your inputs. I have tried by creating both `data.frame` and `matrix` with `NAs`. However, I don't know, how to deal with different length objects from each cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OP is looking to `merge` a list of data.frames instead of `cbind`

Following should do the trick.

```
DF.LIST <- lapply(1:5, function(x) {
    rows <- sample(1:5, 1)
    data.frame(Var1 = sample(1:5, rows), Freq = sample(5:10, rows))
})

DF.LIST
## [[1]]
##   Var1 Freq
## 1    2    6
## 2    4    7
## 3    3    9
## 4    5   10
## 
## [[2]]
##   Var1 Freq
## 1    3   10
## 2    2    9
## 
## [[3]]
##   Var1 Freq
## 1    4    5
## 2    3    6
## 
## [[4]]
##   Var1 Freq
## 1    1    6
## 2    2   10
## 3    5    7
## 4    3    9
## 5    4    8
## 
## [[5]]
##   Var1 Freq
## 1    5   10
##
```

**OPTION 1**

Problem with `Reduce` & `merge` combo if used directly on such a list is that it will just end up merging with both `Var1` and `Freq` columns. To avoid that we first rename the second column in each data.frame by adding a index number. After that `Reduce` and `merge` combo should give what OP wants.

```
for (i in 1:length(DF.LIST)) {
    names(DF.LIST[[i]]) <- c("Var1", paste0("Freq", i))
}


Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), DF.LIST)
##   Var1 Freq1 Freq2 Freq3 Freq4 Freq5
## 1    1    NA    NA    NA     6    NA
## 2    2     6     9    NA    10    NA
## 3    3     9    10     6     9    NA
## 4    4     7    NA     5     8    NA
## 5    5    10    NA    NA     7    10
```

**OPTION 2**

You can try following on original `DF.LIST` directly, but you still need to take care of the column names in the result then.

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "Var1", all = T), DF.LIST)
##   Var1 Freq.x Freq.y Freq.x Freq.y Freq
## 1    1     NA      6     NA      9   NA
## 2    2      7     NA     NA      8   NA
## 3    3     NA      5     NA      7    7
## 4    4     NA      7      5      5   10
## 5    5      9      9      7      6   NA

Warning messages:
1: In merge.data.frame(..., by = "Var1", all = T) :
  column names ‘Freq.x’, ‘Freq.y’ are duplicated in the result
2: In merge.data.frame(..., by = "Var1", all = T) :
  column names ‘Freq.x’, ‘Freq.y’ are duplicated in the result
```